# Publish two similar iPhone apps on AppStore to support customers using two distinct version of my web application

Tags: ios

I have my enterprise application (**intranet** web application) released long back.  
 I also have an iPhone app on AppStore to provide some essential web application functionalities on mobile.
This iPhone app runs against the webapis exposed by this web application and is strongly dependent on it.

I have recently released a new version of my web application which is **substantially different** from the previous version (technically) and is a major release.
**Although it caters to the same business functionality.** 
When I say a major release I mean the entities, signalR version etc are totally incompatible with the previous one.

Now I have to release a mobile app similar to the one I already have on AppStore but running against the new webapis exposed by the new version of webapplication.

> I have to keep on supporting Clients using both of the versions of my enterprise application and cannot have a single iPhone app catering to both due to the strong incompatibility between the two versions of the webapplication.

But going through the Apple Developer site I found below

> *[App Store Review Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/)
>   2.20 Developers "spamming" the App Store with many versions of similar apps will be removed from the iOS Developer Program*

I am really confused in releasing the new app which is similar to the previous one but

- Differs substantially in code base
- Has a different App Icon, AppName and AppID offcourse.
- Is not intended for spamming but for business continuity.

Please help me as I am clueless on this.

**Note: I have already gone through all the related posts on publishing similar iOS Apps but somehow didn't receive any inputs on this specific case.**

Comment: experts please update me with your views on this.

Comment: It sounds like a day will come when users of the "old" version will have to migrate to the new version. Is that so?

Comment: That's expected but is not mandatory. Someone already having the old version of our software suite, if not interested can continue using it. In that case there should be an application in AppStore supporting that version. However for all the users of the new software suite there should be another similar app available in AppStore.

Comment: So, your question basically is, if "two" qualifies as "many", right? My first suspicion would be "no". In my personal experience as an App Store user, Ii encountered several apps in the past, that were supplemented by a successor app, while both version were available in the App Store simultaneously. Substantial differences in the code base that only affect the networking code may be hard to spot by an app reviewer while interacting with the new version, so you could use this opportunity to freshen up th UI, making it obvious that this app is a new development.

Comment: It's not that the difference in code is only to support networking. The new app is written from scratch using Xamarin.iOS, while the old one was a native App. Moreover the entities, function names, viewcontroller names etc are mostly different. Yes, this includes the different SignalR versions as well. Will that qualify as a new app then and not a contender for a spamming app?

Answer (score 1):

While it would be preferable from an OOP point of view - if the UI and UX of both apps are the same - to allow the app's user (or the app itself) to select the correct data provider w.r.t. your web application's version, e.g. have interchangeable implementations that yield the same results depending on the backend, your approach might not be considered 'spamming' the store.

That guideline is intended to hold back developers just changing assets and names of apps (mostly games) and release basically the same codebase 100 times, maximizing efficiency and getting promoted as 'new app' regulary.

Seeing as you already made the conceptually bad decission to develop two different apps, submit both (or seeing as the old one might already be in the store, the new one) and see what review says; there's no harm in trying.

Comment: When I started with the development of the new app, I already had the old app in AppStore (this is corresponding to the old version of the software suite .. webapis and all). The decision to develop the new app was made only due to the substantial incompatibility between the two software versions. To name few of these differences ... the SignalR version on the older server and on old iphone app were compatable. But that was different on the new software. To develop a single app one has to switch SignalR dlls depending on the backend software. So, it was not a bad decision to go this way.

Comment: It might not have been a financially or practically bad decision, but it was a bad conceptual one. Reusable and interchangeable code would have made this way easier. I didn't say it was an overall bad decision. Also, generally speaking, when such things change, there might be different APIs, but implementation details at the server should not effect the clients; if the APIs are fundamentally different, as per interchangeable client code.